# Is it possible to close a http connection without any response?

Tags: apache, security, connection

How can I close a http connection with apache without any response? I would like to close the connection without any response to a request if I detect that the request is a hacking attack.

Now I have something like that:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Hacking-Tool

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sun, 30 Dec 2012 19:00:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.0 (Linux/SUSE) mod_ssl/2.2.0 PHP/5.1.2 SVN/1.4.6
Content-Length: 13
Connection: close
Content-Type: plain/text; charset=utf-8

Stop hacking!
```

How can I simply close the connection so that the hacker cannot guess that I'm running a linux system. I know that I can reduce the server signature this does not matter.

Comment: You can simply close the TCP connection.  You could also remove the `Server:` header.

Comment: I updated my question **how** can I close the connection. The server header cannot be removed so far I know.

Comment: Prefered would be PHP a simply die or exit returns some output which I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried a `nph-` CGI script? If you output nothing from such a script, it should translate to the HTTP client receiving nothing.

Comment: @Celada can you give me an example?

Comment: @rekire Honestly, I haven't used `nph-` CGI scripts in, oh, probably more than 15 years. You're probably better off just Googling it than getting an example from me. It's a way to tell the web server to simply dump the output from the CGI script to the client instead of postprocessing it and adding its own headers. It may not help you anyway if you want to use PHP, because PHP is generally executed not as a CGI script but directly through an Apache module.

Comment: I guess you can try to hide the server details via the config file. try `ServerSignature Off`. This isn't exactly what you want but it should work. **edit** oh you have edited your question, uhmmm, You could do an approach where you have a common .php file to detect hacking, and close the connection if the conditions are met. And include it to all your files. Or something like that, just my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way to achive what I want:

```
# Default hosts which will simply drop the connection
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SecRuleEngine On
    SecAction "id:1,drop,phase:1"
</VirtualHost>
```

This requires that mod secure2 is installed and will drop all connection with unkown hosts. Be aware that you cannot access in that case your server via IP! If you need that add a vhost for your server IP

Answer (score 1):

You've asked two questions, try to avoid that :).

First is you want prevent OS/app fingerprinting. You can do this by removing server header, and changing apache error pages... and still with some probability attacker would be able to guess your os and http server. You can use [Apache Mod Security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) to help yourself.

Second is closing connection without proper http response header after application level, logic execution (your app determines if request is a hacking attempt). In php I think you cannot do this. When parser is executed I think that response is already prepared by apache, and if parser does not return anything empty response or error response would be send by apache itself. And I think if you use some header filtering, and just return plain string "Hacking attempt detected. Administratiors were notified. Legal repercutions may follow." You will scare some script kiddie pretty well.

P.S. Im curious what hacking attempts will your app be able to detect? Is this CSRF token validation ? Is this simple not authenticated access attempt, or other form of Authorization checks ? Or some security mechanism that you developed ?

Comment: The part about hiding the `Server` header was just for explaining what I want to hide, but this was not part of my question (just in the comments). So far I read something of mod secutiry I think this is a kind of proxy isn't it? About how I detect it, I basically use mod rewrite for that. So if someone tries to access to a non existing phpmyadmin I know this is an attack. So I want to close the connection and put the ip on my firewall black list.

Comment: mod security is just apache module that filters incoming and outgoing data. And can help you secure, or anonymise in your case, application. And I wouldn't bother to close the conn without any headers. I would just return simple message that's it, it's not a big processing burden for apache, so you don't really open a new DoS attack vector in your app.

Comment: Well IMHO it does not open any attack vector if I just close the connection and block all future connections from that host. That would not protect me against DDOS but for DOS. I'll check that mod at home.

Comment: To be clear closing connection instead of dummy response, does nothing for protection, firewall blocking does. So if you add blocking entry in your FW, then it does not change anything, if initial conn is closed without any response or if resp, is quick and simple.

Comment: My idea is that the attacker cannot know what is behind this port. It would be possible to think that behind this port is e.g. skype or another messenger. I simply don't want to give hints. But in general you are right. +1 for now, if this works proper you get the answer accepted ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to to close http connection without sending any response to the client.  But is rather involved.  It shouldn't need to be this difficult.

IP Tables Rules:

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING 1 -m recent --rsource --mask 255.255.255.0 --update --seconds 259200 --name DYN_DROP_IPv4 -j DROP
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT 1 -m recent --rsource --mask 255.255.255.0 --update --seconds 259200 --name DYN_DROP_IPv4 -j DROP

ip6tables -t raw -I PREROUTING 1 -m recent --rsource --mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0:0:0:0 --update --seconds 259200 --name DYN_DROP_IPv6 -j DROP
ip6tables -t raw -I OUTPUT 1 -m recent --rsource --mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0:0:0:0 --update --seconds 259200 --name DYN_DROP_IPv6 -j DROP
```

httpd config rewrite rule to run the script:

```
# The network mask must be the same as the iptables rule mask
Define DynDropIP_QueryString '\
?action=+\
&addr=%{REMOTE_ADDR}\
&port=%{REMOTE_PORT}\
&mask_ipv4=255.255.255.0\
&mask_ipv6=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:0:0:0:0\
&remote_host=%{REMOTE_HOST}\
&server_name=%{SERVER_NAME}\
&server_port=%{SERVER_PORT}\
&request_method=%{REQUEST_METHOD}\
&request_uri=%{REQUEST_URI}\
&http_user_agent=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}\
'

Define BAD_REQUESTS_REGEX '\
^/./|\
^/\.|\
^/[0-9]+|\
^/admin|\
'

Define BAD_BOTS_REGEX '\
^.$|\
11A465|\
Ahrefs|\
ArchiveBot|\
AspiegelBot|\
Baiduspider|\
'

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ${BAD_REQUESTS_REGEX} [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ${BAD_BOTS_REGEX} [NC]

# Dynamic Drop IP Script
RewriteRule ^.* /cgi-bin/DynDropIP${DynDropIP_QueryString} [PT,E=dontlog,L,END]

UnDefine DynDropIP_QueryString
UnDefine BAD_REQUESTS_REGEX
UnDefine BAD_BOTS_REGEX
```

`cgi-bin/DynDropIP`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

main() {
    # Pass query string trough to the named pipe (FIFO file) daemon; Redirect stderr to bit bucket
    fifo_dir='/var/run/DynDropIP/'
    fifo_file='xt_recent_fifo'

    if [[ -p "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "${QUERY_STRING}" 1>"${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" 2>/dev/null
    fi

    response
}


response() {
    # Allow a few seconds for the firewall to be updated before responding (desire firewall to block the response)
    sleep 3

    # Set the HTTP response headers (404 and content type)
    # end of HTTP headers (empty line i.e. 2nd consecutive line feed)
    # Send 404 error page (duplicate of Apache 2.4.6 default 404 page (en))
    printf "%s\n%s\n\n%s\n" \
    "Status: 404 Not Found" \
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" \
"\
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL ${REQUEST_URI} was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>\
"
}


main
```

`/usr/local/libexec/DynDropIP/xt_recent_fifo.sh`
(run this script to start the fifo and daemon)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fifo_dir='/var/run/DynDropIP/'
fifo_file='xt_recent_fifo'
daemon='/usr/local/libexec/DynDropIP/xt_recent_fifo_daemon.sh'

# Prep and clean first

# If fifo dir is not a dir remove and make dir
if [[ ! -d "${fifo_dir}" ]]; then
    rm -f "${fifo_dir}"
    mkdir -p "${fifo_dir}"
fi

# If fifo file exists remove
[ -a "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ] || \
[ -e "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ] || \
[ -f "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ] || \
[ -h "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ] || \
[ -p "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" ] && \
rm -f "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}"

mkfifo -m 666 "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}"

# For SELinux - Allow apache user to write to the fifo
chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}"

tail -f "${fifo_dir}${fifo_file}" | "${daemon}" &
```

`/usr/local/libexec/DynDropIP/xt_recent_fifo_daemon.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

main() {
    # Initialize IP address regex pattern vars
    IP_RegEx

    # Expected query string parameters: action (+/-), addr, port, mask_ipv4, mask_ipv6
    while read QUERY_STRING
    do
        # Parse the query string into associative array
        while IFS='=' read -r -d '&' key value && [[ -n "$key" ]]; do
            declare $key="$value"
        done <<<"${QUERY_STRING}&"

        if validate; then
            if process_address; then
                update_iptables
                logit
#               response
                destroy_tcp_socket
            fi
        fi
    done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
}


# Validate action, address and mask parameters
validate() {
    # Verify action parameter
    if [[ "${action}" != "+" && "${action}" != "-" ]]; then
        return 1    # failed: invalid action
    fi

    # Verify address and mask, set ip version if okay
    if [[ "${addr}" =~ ^${IPV4ADDR}$ && "${mask_ipv4}" =~ ^${IPV4ADDR}$ ]]; then
        ipv=4
    elif [[ "${addr}" =~ ^${IPV6ADDR}$ && "${mask_ipv6}" =~ ^${IPV6ADDR}$ ]]; then
        ipv=6
    else
        return 2    # failed: invalid address or network mask
    fi
}


# Process IPvN address
process_address() {
    if [[ $ipv -eq 4 ]]; then
        ipv4_network_mask
        if ! [[ "${maddr}" =~ ^${IPV4ADDR}$ ]]; then
            return 4    # failed: invalid masked ipv4 address
        fi
    elif [[ $ipv -eq 6 ]]; then
        ipv6_expand_address
        ipv6_native_notation
        ipv6_network_mask
        if ! [[ "${maddr}" =~ ^${IPV6ADDR}$ ]]; then
            return 6    # failed: invalid masked ipv6 address
        fi
    fi
}


# Compress IPv6 address (retain IPv4 dotted decimal or IPv6 native notation)
compress_address() {
    if [[ $addr =~ ^((${IPV6SEG}:){6})((${IPV6SEG}:${IPV6SEG})|(${IPV4ADDR}))$ ]]; then
        local IPv6_Segments IPv4_Segments pattern

        IPv6_Segments=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        IPv4_Segments=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}

        # Suppress hextet leading zeros; Three passes to get each of three
        IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments//:0/:} && IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments//:0/:} && IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments//:0/:}

        # Reconstitute empty hextets with single zero; Two passes to get every other one
        IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments//::/:0:} && IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments//::/:0:}

        # First hextet special cases (0:)
        [[ $IPv6_Segments =~ ^0*([[:xdigit:]]+)(.*) ]] && IPv6_Segments="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

        # Last hextet special cases (:0, only if not followed by IPv4 segment)
        [[ $IPv6_Segments =~ [^:]:$ && -z $IPv4_Segments ]] && IPv6_Segments=$IPv6_Segments'0'

        # Compress longest contiguous hextets of zero to "::" (leftmost tiebreaker).
        for (( i=7; $i>=1; i-- ))
        do
            pattern=''
            for (( j=0; $j<$i; j++ ))
            do
                pattern+=':0'
            done

            # Compress at beginning
            [[ $IPv6_Segments =~ ^0$pattern ]] && IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments/0$pattern/::} && break

            # Compress in the middle or at end
            [[ $IPv6_Segments =~ $pattern:0 ]] && IPv6_Segments=${IPv6_Segments/$pattern:0/::} && break

        done

        # Put address together and remove extra triple colons
        addr=$IPv6_Segments$IPv4_Segments
        addr=${addr/:::/::}
    fi
}


# Expand IPv6 Address (retain dotted decimal or native notation)
ipv6_expand_address() {
    local hextests num_colons additional_hextets

    # Number of hextets in an expanded IPv6 address (native notation)
    hextets=8

    # How many colons in address
    num_colons=${addr//[^:]/}
    num_colons=${#num_colons}

    # Is address IPv4 dotted decimal notation
    [[ $addr =~ :${IPV4ADDR}$ ]] && hextets=$((hextets-1))      # ::ffff:0:0/96, ::ffff:0:0:0/96, 64:ff9b::/96

    # Fix up beginning and end
    [[ $addr =~ ^:: ]] && addr='0'$addr
    [[ $addr =~ ::$ ]] && addr=$addr'0'

    # Create additional hextets
    additional_hextets=':'
    for (( i=$num_colons; $i<$hextets; i++ ))
    do
        additional_hextets+='0:'
    done

    # Insert additional hextets (replace ::)
    addr=${addr/::/$additional_hextets}
}


# Convert from IPv4 dotted decimal to IPv6 native notation (retain compressed / expanded)
ipv6_native_notation() {
    local expanded_flag
    # Ensure working with an expanded address
    [[ $addr =~ :: ]] && ipv6_expand_address && expanded_flag=1

    # Is address IPv4 dotted decimal notation
    if [[ $addr =~ ^(.*:)(${IPV4ADDR})$ ]]; then
        local IPv6_Segments IPv4_Segments
        local s1 s2 s3 s4 s1s2 s3s4

        IFS=. read -r s1 s2 s3 s4 <<< ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}    # IPv4 Segments 1, 2, 3, & 4

        s1s2=$(( ($s1 * 0x100) + $s2 ))                     # Hextet 7
        s3s4=$(( ($s3 * 0x100) + $s4 ))                     # Hextet 8

        IPv6_Segments=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                    # Hextets 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        IPv4_Segments=$( printf "%x:%x" "$s1s2" "$s3s4" )   # As Hextets 7 & 8

        # Return converted native notation address (expanded)
        if [[ -n $IPv6_Segments && -n $IPv4_Segments ]]; then
            addr=$IPv6_Segments$IPv4_Segments
        fi
    fi

    # Revert expansion
    [[ $expanded_flag -eq 1 ]] && compress_address
}


# Convert from IPv6 native to IPv4 dotted decimal notation (retain compressed / expanded)
ipv6_dotted_decimal_notation() {
    local expanded_flag
    # Ensure working with an expanded address
    [[ $addr =~ :: ]] && ipv6_expand_address && expanded_flag=1

    # Is address IPv6 native notation
    if [[ $addr =~ ^(.*:)(${IPV6SEG}:${IPV6SEG})$ ]]; then
        local IPv6_Segments IPv4_Segments
        local s1 s2 UB LB

        IFS=: read -r s1 s2 <<< ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}          # IPv6 Segments 7 & 8

        UB=$((0xFF00))                                      # Upper Byte mask
        LB=$((0x00FF))                                      # Lower Byte mask

        IPv6_Segments=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}                    # Hextets 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        IPv4_Segments=$(((16#$s1 & $UB) / $LB)).$((16#$s1 & $LB)).$(((16#$s2 & $UB) / $LB)).$((16#$s2 & $LB))

        # Return converted dotted decimal notation address (expanded)
        if [[ -n $IPv6_Segments && -n $IPv4_Segments ]]; then
            addr=$IPv6_Segments$IPv4_Segments
        fi
    fi

    # Revert expansion
    [[ $expanded_flag -eq 1 ]] && compress_address
}


# Apply IPv4 network mask
ipv4_network_mask() {
    local s1 s2 s3 s4
    local m1 m2 m3 m4
    mask=$mask_ipv4     # Mask is also used in logit

    IFS=. read -r s1 s2 s3 s4 <<< $addr
    IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< $mask

    maddr="$((s1 & m1)).$((s2 & m2)).$((s3 & m3)).$((s4 & m4))"
}


# Apply IPv6 network mask
ipv6_network_mask() {
    local s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8
    local m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8
    mask=$mask_ipv6     # Mask is also used in logit

    IFS=: read -r s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 <<< $addr
    IFS=: read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 <<< $mask

    maddr=$( \
    printf "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x" \
    "$((0x$s1 & 0x$m1))" "$((0x$s2 & 0x$m2))" "$((0x$s3 & 0x$m3))" "$((0x$s4 & 0x$m4))" \
    "$((0x$s5 & 0x$m5))" "$((0x$s6 & 0x$m6))" "$((0x$s7 & 0x$m7))" "$((0x$s8 & 0x$m8))" \
    )
}


# Update table
update_iptables() {
    # Add/Remove validated address to/from the xt_recent table (action parameter +/- determines add/remove)
    # Redirect both stdout & stderr to null device so as not to inadvertently provide it to web user
    if [[ -n $action && -n $maddr && -n $ipv ]]; then
        printf "%s%s" $action $maddr 2>/dev/null \
        |/usr/bin/tee /proc/net/xt_recent/DYN_DROP_IPv$ipv \
        1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    fi
}


# Log entry
logit() {
    local log_dir='/var/log/iptables/DYN_DROP_IP/'
    local log_file='DYN_DROP_IPv'$ipv'.log'

    mkdir -p "$log_dir"

    # Address field width padding (string length, field width, pad chr/str, pad chr/str width)
    local field_width=0
    [[ $ipv -eq 4 ]] && field_width=15
    [[ $ipv -eq 6 ]] && field_width=39

    local  apad=$( logit_pad ${#addr}  $field_width '   ' 4 )
    local  mpad=$( logit_pad ${#mask}  $field_width '   ' 4 )
    local mapad=$( logit_pad ${#maddr} $field_width '   ' 4 )

    # Write log entry
    printf '%s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n' \
    "$( date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %a' )" \
    "$ipv" \
    "$action" \
    "$addr$apad" \
    "$maddr$mapad" \
    "$mask$mpad" \
    "$remote_host" \
    "$server_name" \
    "$server_port" \
    "$request_method" \
    "$request_uri" \
    "$http_user_agent" \
    >> "$log_dir$log_file"

#   # Truncate to last 200 entries (skip header row)
#
#   if [[ $ipv -eq 4 ]]; then
#       local log_header='Date       Time     Day   IPv Action  IP Address  Blocked Network Network Mask    Client  Web Site    Scheme  Method  URI User Agent'
#   elif [[ $ipv -eq 6 ]]; then
#       local log_header='Date       Time     Day   IPv Action      IP Address                          Blocked Network                         Network Mask                            Client  Web Site    Scheme  Method  URI User Agent'
#   fi
#
#   printf '%s\n%s\n' \
#   "$log_header" \
#   "$(tail -n +2 $log_dir$log_file | tail -n -200)" \
#   > "$log_dir$log_file"
}


# Field width padding
logit_pad() {
    local str_length=$1
    local field_width=$2
    local pad_chr=$3
    local pad_chr_width=$4  # e.g. tab width

    local pad_length=$(( ($field_width - $str_length)  / $pad_chr_width ))

    local pad_string=''
    for (( i=0; $i<$pad_length; i++ ))
    do
        pad_string+=$pad_chr
    done

    printf "%s" "$pad_string"
}    


IP_RegEx() {
    # IPv4 Regular Expressions
    IPV4SEG='(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9])?[0-9])'         # doted decimal notation; no leading 0 (octal) or 0x (hexadecimal)
    IPV4ADDR='(('${IPV4SEG}'\.){3,3}('${IPV4SEG}'){1,1})'
    IPV4CIDR='(3[0-2]|[12]?[0-9])'


    # IPv6 Regular Expressions
    IPV6SEG='[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}'                              # colon hextet notation; leading 0 permitted

    IPV6SEG8='('${IPV6SEG}':){7,7}('${IPV6SEG}'){1,1}'      # 1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8
    IPV6SEG7='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,7}(:''){1,1}'               # 1::                                 1:2:3:4:5:6:7::
    IPV6SEG6='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,6}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,1}'     # 1::8               1:2:3:4:5:6::8   1:2:3:4:5:6::8
    IPV6SEG5='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,5}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,2}'     # 1::7:8             1:2:3:4:5::7:8   1:2:3:4:5::8
    IPV6SEG4='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,4}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,3}'     # 1::6:7:8           1:2:3:4::6:7:8   1:2:3:4::8
    IPV6SEG3='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,3}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,4}'     # 1::5:6:7:8         1:2:3::5:6:7:8   1:2:3::8
    IPV6SEG2='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,2}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,5}'     # 1::4:5:6:7:8       1:2::4:5:6:7:8   1:2::8
    IPV6SEG1='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,1}(:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,6}'     # 1::3:4:5:6:7:8     1::3:4:5:6:7:8   1::8

    IPV6SEG0=':((:'${IPV6SEG}'){1,7}|:)'                    #  ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8    ::2:3:4:5:6:7:8  ::8       ::

    IPV6LLZI='[fF][eE]80:(:'${IPV6SEG}'){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}'  # fe80::7:8%eth0     fe80::7:8%1  (link-local IPv6 addresses with zone index)

    IPV6V4MAP='(::|(0{1,4}:){5})[fF]{4}:'${IPV4ADDR}        # ::ffff:d.d.d.d        (::ffff:0:0/96 IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses)
    IPV6V4TRN='(::|(0{1,4}:){4})[fF]{4}:0{1,4}:'${IPV4ADDR} # ::ffff:0:d.d.d.d      (::ffff:0:0:0/96 IPv4-translated addresses)
    IPV6V4CMP='(::|(0:){6})'${IPV4ADDR}                     # ::d.d.d.d             (IPv4-compatible (0::/96 deprecated by RFC4291))
#   IPV6V4TRN='::([fF]{4}(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}'${IPV4ADDR}  # ::d.d.d.d  ::ffff:d.d.d.d  ::ffff:0:d.d.d.d   (IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses and IPv4-translated addresses))

    IPV6V4AMP='64:[fF]{2}9b:(:|(0{1,4}:){4})'${IPV4ADDR}    # 64:ff9b::d.d.d.d      (64:ff9b::/96 IPv4 translation addresses (algorithmic mapping RFC6052))
    IPV6V4LUT='64:[fF]{2}9b:1:(:|(0{1,4}:){3})'${IPV4ADDR}  # 64:ff9b:1::d.d.d.d    (64:ff9b:1::/48 Local-Use IPv4/IPv6 Translation RFC8215)
#   IPV6V4EMB='('${IPV6SEG}':){1,4}:'${IPV4ADDR}            # 2001:db8:3:4::d.d.d.d 64:ff9b::d.d.d.d (IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Address)

    IPV6ADDR='('\
'('${IPV6SEG8}')|('${IPV6SEG7}')|('${IPV6SEG6}')|('${IPV6SEG5}')|('${IPV6SEG4}')|('${IPV6SEG3}')|('${IPV6SEG2}')|('${IPV6SEG1}')|('${IPV6SEG0}')|'\
'('${IPV6LLZI}')|('${IPV6V4MAP}')|('${IPV6V4TRN}')|('${IPV6V4CMP}')|('${IPV6V4AMP}')|('${IPV6V4LUT}')'\
')'

    IPV6CIDR='(12[0-8]|(1[01]|[1-9])?[0-9])'

    PORT='([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])'
}


response() {
    # Allow a few seconds for the firewall to be updated before responding (desire firewall to block the response)
    sleep 3

    # Set the HTTP response headers (404 and content type)
    # end of HTTP headers (empty line i.e. 2nd consecutive line feed)
    # Send 404 error page (duplicate of Apache 2.4.6 default 404 page (en))
    printf "%s\n%s\n\n%s\n" \
    "Status: 404 Not Found" \
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" \
"\
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL ${REQUEST_URI} was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>\
"
}


# On linux kernel >= 4.9 you can use the ss command from iproute2 with key -K
# ss -K dst 192.168.1.214 dport = 49029
# the kernel has to be compiled with CONFIG_INET_DIAG_DESTROY option enabled.
destroy_tcp_socket() {
#   if [[ "${port}" =~ ^${PORT}$ ]]; then           # Strictly Regex method

#   local -i port="10#${port}" 2> /dev/null         # Convert to integer method
#   if [[ $port -ge 1 && $port -le 65535 ]]; then

    # Is integer between 1 and 65535 (inclusive)
    local int_regex='^[0-9]+$'
    if [[ "$port" =~ $int_regex && $port -ge 1 && $port -le 65535 ]]; then
#       ss -K dst $addr dport = $port
        ss -K dst $addr:$port \
        1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    fi
}


main
```

Comment: Amazing solution, when I have some free time I will check it.